# Chrome not displaying text properly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Any ideas on why this code works perfectly in Firefox (that is, if the text is longer than the width it continues below) but in Chrome it doesn't work? (e.g the text keeps going to the right)

The CSS:

```
#leftnav {
 width: 18%;
 float: left;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: 15px 0 0 0;
 margin-left: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 padding: 5px 5px 30px 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}
#leftnav h2 {
 font: normal 17px "Geneva", Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 color: #ff4800;
 margin: 20px 0 5px 10px;
}
```

The PHP/HTML:

```
<h2>
<a href="index.php?site=<?php echo urlencode($value);?>"><?php echo $value;?></a>
</h2>
```

Thank you very much for any input!!!

Comment: The php is, pretty much, irrelevant here. CSS, like JavaScript, works with the rendered (x)html, not the server-side code.

Comment: where is the html for #leftnav

Comment: Wait, nevermind, when it's an unbroken string (such as URL), it does not break the same as in Firefox 4. http://jsfiddle.net/7nruR/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `word-wrap: break-word`:

```
#leftnav h2 {
 font: normal 17px "Geneva", Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, Verdana;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 color: #ff4800;
 margin: 20px 0 5px 10px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7nruR/2/

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap